# Filter data frame based on multiple conditions in another data frame

Tags: r, subset

I have two data frames:

- `df` where for single `x` there are multiple values `y`
- `matchDf` which defines constraints I would like to use to filter `df`

I would like to filter only rows where `y` is lower or equal to `max_y` given that `x` falls in interval `<x_from, x_to)`

Is there any way to do this in R (without SQL I used below)?

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
x y
100 0.1
100 0.2
100 0.3
250 0.2
250 0.3
250 0.4
375 0.2
375 0.25
375 0.35
420 0.15
420 0.16
420 0.17
500 0.23
500 0.55')

matchDf <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
x_from x_to max_y
0 300 .2
300 500 .3
500 99999 .5
')

library(sqldf)

sqldf('select a.* 
      from 
        df a 
        join matchDf b on (a.x >= b.x_from 
                           and a.x < b.x_to 
                           and a.y <= b.max_y)'
      )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df$y <= matchDf$max_y[cut(df$x, c(0,matchDf$x_to))],]
     x    y
1  100 0.10
2  100 0.20
4  250 0.20
7  375 0.20
8  375 0.25
10 420 0.15
11 420 0.16
12 420 0.17
13 500 0.23
```

What's happening here is that `cut` is giving you which row in `matchDf` each observation in `df` should be in. Then, you just use that as a positional row extraction vector, and state the conditional relationship for `y` using `<=`.

To see how `cut` works, just pull it out of the expression:

```
> cut(df$x, c(0,matchDf$x_to))
 [1] (0,300]   (0,300]   (0,300]   (0,300]   (0,300]   (0,300]   (300,500] (300,500] (300,500] (300,500] (300,500] (300,500] (300,500] (300,500]
Levels: (0,300] (300,500] (500,1e+05]
```

The level labels are irrelevant, because `[` uses the underlying integer values to extract.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
df[mapply(function(x, y) {
               y <= matchDf$max_y[x >=matchDf$x_from  & x < matchDf$x_to]
            }, x=df$x, y=df$y), ]
     # x    y
# 1  100 0.10
# 2  100 0.20
# 4  250 0.20
# 7  375 0.20
# 8  375 0.25
# 10 420 0.15
# 11 420 0.16
# 12 420 0.17
# 13 500 0.23
```

The function `mapply` permits, for each couple `(x,y)`, to know if `y` is lower or equal to the appropriate `max_y` value and is applied to each "couple" of `df` and return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, then `df` is subsetted according to the `mapply` result.